# Unable to create process : .ui to .py

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have been trying for a long time to generate a python code frome qtDesigner but I always have the same issue :

**The command I used** : `pyuic5 ExtraInfo_Design.ui -o ExtraInfo_Designui.py`

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\Dorian\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\lDorian\Desktop\extrInfo\pyuic5.exe" ExtraInfo_Design.ui -o ExtraInfo_Designui.py'
```

I think that all these problems happen because I changed the name of my laptop so I have other files that had been created "lDorian".

I have tried to open the shell as ana administrator.
I had tried to generate the code from a (.bat) file.
I had tried to add python path to the path directory.

Thanks, folks.

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm sorry but I didn't really understand your solution.

Comment: I have other issues : ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Dorian\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\Users\Dorian\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Dorian\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\pyuic.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 n’est pas une application Win32 valide.```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling Anaconda and all the version of python/pyqt that I already have,
I opened the cmd on Windows but I had the same problem.

The **solution** is:

1. After reinstalling all and deleting the python link in the path environment.
2. Open the Anaconda **Powershell** Prompt (not Anaconda Prompt) as an administrator
3. Type pip install pyqt5
4. then run : `pyuic5 fileName.ui -o fileName.py`

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I get it from your question and the error message, you changed your laptop username from *lDorian* to *Dorian* . For programs that set the path variable during installation, this is now wrong as you see in your error message.

For python the path starts with "c:\users\Dorian", for pyuic5 it start with "C:\Users\lDorian" which I guess is the user that does not exist anymore.

The python path you changed, so it looks fine now. Also change the path for pyuic5 and it should work.

If you still encounter problems, a clean reinstall of python and qt should do the job and might be faster than searching for all misset paths.

Comment: Thank you @Janine, I had reinstall Anoconda and all.